# Regex match first character but not second of same?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

For example: `b-c--` I want to match the first two `-` but not the last.

I tried different combination of lookaheads but I can't get it to work. The closes I got was `-(?!-)` but it matches the first and last instead of the middle.

Comment: Please edit your question and tags to tell us what framework/library/language you're using. Otherwise, the question can't be answered.

Comment: For this particular example, you can simply use [`-(?!$)`](https://regex101.com/r/ikO1UO/1)

Comment: Please give more examples.  It is not entirely clear what the regex logic is.

Comment: You're on a good way. But instead of using a lookahead, you should use a lookbehind. Give a try to `(?<!-)-`.

Comment: @piojo done
@TimBiegeleisen At the moment I need this to split hotkeys (Ctrl-somekey, including `Ctrl--`), but I was wondering just in general how one might match the first instance of something but not the second if it directly follows.
@Gurman I think I'll use that for now, but it doesn't completely answer my question for other cases. e.g. `-- --` it matches the first two.
@PJProudhon Sorry I didn't tag the language, but javascript doesn't support negative lookbehinds.